# How do we re-use Paragraph items?

Tags: 8, paragraphs

Paragraph items are only available to their parent entities. But is there any known way to make it possible to re-use existing Paragraph items?

Comment: Reusable paragraphs are now possible with the Paragraphs sub-module [Paragraphs Library](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/paragraphs/tree/8.x-1.x/modules/paragraphs_library), which requires the [Entity Usage](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_usage) module.

Answer (score 13):

Paragraphs is focused on reusing layouts not content. The most obvious implication is on revisions.

In a standard reference field you reference the latest revision of the target. When you roll back the parent the target keeps the actual content. Paragraphs on the other hand keeps track of the revisions and allows you to rollback an entity including the content of the paragraphs that are owned by the entity. And that's the problem, if Paragraphs would allow reusing, how a rollback should be handled for paragraphs that are shared among multiple host entities.

So Paragraphs is by design not a tool for reusing content.

But there is good news, there will be a library entity, which will make this possible:

> **Implement Library entity type**
>
> We want to make this separate entity type:
>   - Autosync with bundles + fields of Paragraphs
>   - Still add a label (plus more administrational fields if needed for managing them).
>
> A reusable paragraph will be typically stored as a clone of a previous
>   paragraph. It is NOT a composite of the original. Reusable paragraphs
>   have an own separate edit form and can also be creted independently
>   through the Add form.
>
> A user can click the action "Add to library" that makes a paragraph
>   reusable. This clones the paragraph and the original host entity will
>   have a new paragraph instance added that contains a reference to the
>   effective reusable paragraph.
>
> The paragraph type "From Library" contains nothing but a entity
>   reference to the reusable paragraph. Initially, using autocomplete
>   widget here is fine.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2843917

Comment: And just to add an alternative—you can use [Entity Construction Kit](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) + [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) to get a setup very much like Paragraphs, but with first-class entities that can be reused more easily (at least at the time of this writing).

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant by using *standard* reference fields. I would prefer at the moment a custom entity build with *Drupal Console*, until there is a stable release of *ECK* or *Paragraphs Collection*.

Comment: We've overcome this issue by combining paragraphs and blocks. For each paragraph type, also create a block type with a single entity reference field to that particular paragraphs type and a cardinality of 1. Each of these blocks is reusable. Works great in panels!